# Voltage Drop - Sizing Feeders

Tags: voltage

I am reviewing a value engineering proposal consisting of downsizing the main feeders to the moveable bridge. for the voltage drop, they calculated the total current draw for the worst case scenario feeder, consisting of miscellaneous equipment (transformers, brakes, receptacles etc.) and 2 100 hp 3-phase motors (fed from VFD's). In their calculation, they used the running amps (55.8A ea) for the motor current draw. shouldn't they use the full load amps (124A ea) ?

Comment: When you asked them why they used 55.8, what did they say was their reason?

Comment: I have not yet asked them, I wanted to make sure i wasn't missing anything before I responded.

Comment: Designers rarely operate at FLA unless it is an emergency. It’s just a bad practise and ignores the MTBF thermal effects

Comment: There could be several reasons that the sum of the input currents to the VFDs might never equal the sum of the rated currents of the motors. Perhaps the speed is variable because the fastest movement is used only for the minimum-load part of the movement sequence. Since we can only guess, I am voting to close the question as primarily asking for opinions.